# PHP class/method type inheritance setting the class as static or setting all the containing methods as static

Tags: php, class, inheritance, methods, static

If I wanted to have a class of static functions, would it be smarter to define the class as `static` and let the methods inherit that or define each method as static without setting a type for the class. My goal is to have a class of data type validation functions that I can call without having to create an instance of the containing class. Which method would be the better option for my intended purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP doesn't support static classes. you must declare methods you need as static.

Answer (score 0):

in php there is no such thing as static class.
use static functions or regular function. same thing